# Can i change wordpress emoji src from http://s.w.org/ to my site?

Tags: php, emoji

Can I change WordPress emoji src from http://s.w.org/ to my site?

I just want to replace all emoji links from http://s.w.org/ to my site URL and I will use my own emoji images.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use the [`emoji_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/emoji_url/) filter. Note there are a [few other](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/195b2273576b9fdca7f76aa2a31ea14a7defc682/wp-includes/formatting.php#L5008-L5042) filters available as well.

A simple example would be

```
add_filter( 'emoji_url', function( $url ) {
    return 'https://www.myowndomain.com/emoji/72x72/';
} );
```